# How to check number of paragraphs inside a div and delete some of them using jQuery?

Tags: jquery

I am new to jQuery and I am appending some paragraphs dynamically with a socket inside a div, so I want to know if the number of paragraphs exceeds certain number. If the number of paragraphs exceed, say 10, I would like to stay with the last 10 and remove the other ones. 
This is how I am appending the paragraphs:

```
socket.on("response", function (text) {
      $("div.paragraphs").append(
        '<p>' + text + '</p>'
      );
  });
```

This is what I am trying:

```
$("div.paragraphs").change(function () {
    const matched = $("p");
    console.log("Number of paragraphs in div = " + matched.length);
  });
```

However, nothing shows in the console.
I would like to do something like this, but don't know if I am correct:

```
$("div.paragraphs").change(function () {
    const matched = $("p");
    if(matched.length){
      $('p:lt(matched.length-10)', 'div.paragraphs').remove()
    }
});
```

Is this the correct approach?

Comment: *and I am appending some paragraphs dynamically inside a div* Can you show the code that does this?

Comment: @CertainPerformance sure, let me edit the question.

Comment: The `change` method works with input elements only. Div elements do not trigger the change event. You need to place the code that checks for the number of paragraphs inside the code/function that dynamically adds new paragraphs.

Comment: @KostasX thanks! Now it's logging the number of paragraphs in the console.

Comment: please check my answer for an insight on what you wanted to do with $('p:lt(matched.length-10)', 'div.paragraphs'). I think you may like it c:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `change` event will not fire when *elements* change - it'll only fire when input-like elements' *values* change. While you could observe changes with a MutationObserver, it would be much more elegant to fire your paragraph-checker after you append a paragraph (or after all paragraphs are appended, if batched).

Since it looks like a single new `<p>` is appended on every socket message, you can keep a running total of the number of `<p>`s appended so far, and once that reaches the limit, run `$("div.paragraphs > p:first-child").remove()` to remove the first `<p>` (the oldest one):

```
let pCount = 0;
socket.on("response", function(text) {
  $("div.paragraphs").append(
    '<p>' + text + '</p>'
  );
  pCount++;
  if (pCount > 10) {
    $("div.paragraphs").first().remove();
  }
});
```

Live demo (using `setInterval` instead of sockets):

```js
let pCount = 0;
setInterval(() => {
  $("div.paragraphs").append(
    '<p>' + Math.random() + '</p>'
  );
  pCount++;
  if (pCount > 10) {
    $("div.paragraphs > p:first-child").remove();
  }
}, 400);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="paragraphs">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's some sample code to do what you describe:

(I have replaced the response.on with a button that manually adds paragraphs, just for a proof-of-concept. You can move the code that removes the first element in your callback function.)

```js
let counter = 0;

$("button").on("click", function() {

      $("div.paragraphs").append(
        '<p>Text' +  (counter++) + '</p>'
      );


    if ( $("div.paragraphs p").length > 10 ){
      $("div.paragraphs > p:first").remove()
    }

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button>Add</button>
<div class="paragraphs"></div>
```

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/kostasx/pen/zYvZxVj?editors=1010)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this mind my code comments:

```
socket.on("response", function (text) {
  $("div.paragraphs").append(
    '<p>' + text + '</p>'
  ); //now here... this means if you insert a new element and it is the 11nth, it will get erased... maybe you meant prepend?
  maintain_ten_elements(); //this is here since I assume you want the div never to be past 10.
});

 function maintain_ten_elements(){
    $("div.paragraphs p:nth(9)").nextAll().remove(); //sexy single line of code, takes the the 10nth element (9, because it starts from 0) and then takes all the elements after it (11 and on) and removes them.
}
```